# Serializing Eigen::Matrix using Cereal library

Tags: c++, serialization, c++11, eigen, cereal

**UPDATED**: I managed to get it to work after I googled around and read the doxygen comments in code. Problem was that I missed the cast before using `resize()` method and also not using `std::ios::binary` for the streams. If you want to do something similar, better check the answer by Azoth.

I am trying to serialize `Eigen::Matrix` type using Cereal. This is what I have (loosely based on https://gist.github.com/mtao/5798888 and the the types in `cereal/types`):

```
#include <cereal/cereal.hpp>
#include <cereal/archives/binary.hpp>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <fstream>

namespace cereal
{
    template <class Archive, class _Scalar, int _Rows, int _Cols, int _Options, int _MaxRows, int _MaxCols> inline
        typename std::enable_if<traits::is_output_serializable<BinaryData<_Scalar>, Archive>::value, void>::type
        save(Archive & ar, Eigen::Matrix<_Scalar, _Rows, _Cols, _Options, _MaxRows, _MaxCols> const & m)
    {
            int rows = m.rows();
            int cols = m.cols();
            ar(make_size_tag(static_cast<size_type>(rows * cols)));
            ar(rows);
            ar(cols);
            ar(binary_data(m.data(), rows * cols * sizeof(_Scalar)));
        }

    template <class Archive, class _Scalar, int _Rows, int _Cols, int _Options, int _MaxRows, int _MaxCols> inline
        typename std::enable_if<traits::is_input_serializable<BinaryData<_Scalar>, Archive>::value, void>::type
        load(Archive & ar, Eigen::Matrix<_Scalar, _Rows, _Cols, _Options, _MaxRows, _MaxCols> const & m)
    {
            size_type size;
            ar(make_size_tag(size));

            int rows;
            int cols;
            ar(rows);
            ar(cols);

            const_cast<Eigen::Matrix<_Scalar, _Rows, _Cols, _Options, _MaxRows, _MaxCols> &>(m).resize(rows, cols);

            ar(binary_data(const_cast<_Scalar *>(m.data()), static_cast<std::size_t>(size * sizeof(_Scalar))));
        }
}

int main() {
    Eigen::MatrixXd test = Eigen::MatrixXd::Random(10, 3);
    std::ofstream out = std::ofstream("eigen.cereal", std::ios::binary);
    cereal::BinaryOutputArchive archive_o(out);
    archive_o(test);

    std::cout << "test:" << std::endl << test << std::endl;

    out.close();

    Eigen::MatrixXd test_loaded;
    std::ifstream in = std::ifstream("eigen.cereal", std::ios::binary);
    cereal::BinaryInputArchive archive_i(in);
    archive_i(test_loaded);

    std::cout << "test loaded:" << std::endl << test_loaded << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: If you can I'd drop the const for the matrix in load().  It also looks like serializing the size (row*col) is superfluous.  Load() could do the multiplication itself.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your code is nearly correct but has a few mistakes:

You don't need to be making the `size_tag` since you are serializing the number of rows and columns explicitly.  Generally cereal uses `size_tag` for resizable containers like vectors or lists.  Even though the matrix can resize, it makes more sense just to serialize the rows and columns explicitly.

1. Your load function should accept its parameter by non-const reference
2. You shouldn't use operator= with the `std::ofstream` objects
3. It's better practice to let scoping and RAII handle closing/tearing down of the `std::ofstream` as well as cereal archives (the binary archive will flush its contents immediately, but in general cereal archives are only guaranteed to flush their contents on destruction)

Here's a version that compiles and produces correct output under g++ and clang++:

```
#include <cereal/cereal.hpp>
#include <cereal/archives/binary.hpp>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <fstream>

namespace cereal
{
  template <class Archive, class _Scalar, int _Rows, int _Cols, int _Options, int _MaxRows, int _MaxCols> inline
    typename std::enable_if<traits::is_output_serializable<BinaryData<_Scalar>, Archive>::value, void>::type
    save(Archive & ar, Eigen::Matrix<_Scalar, _Rows, _Cols, _Options, _MaxRows, _MaxCols> const & m)
    {
      int32_t rows = m.rows();
      int32_t cols = m.cols();
      ar(rows);
      ar(cols);
      ar(binary_data(m.data(), rows * cols * sizeof(_Scalar)));
    }

  template <class Archive, class _Scalar, int _Rows, int _Cols, int _Options, int _MaxRows, int _MaxCols> inline
    typename std::enable_if<traits::is_input_serializable<BinaryData<_Scalar>, Archive>::value, void>::type
    load(Archive & ar, Eigen::Matrix<_Scalar, _Rows, _Cols, _Options, _MaxRows, _MaxCols> & m)
    {
      int32_t rows;
      int32_t cols;
      ar(rows);
      ar(cols);

      m.resize(rows, cols);

      ar(binary_data(m.data(), static_cast<std::size_t>(rows * cols * sizeof(_Scalar))));
    }
}

int main() {
  Eigen::MatrixXd test = Eigen::MatrixXd::Random(10, 3);

  {
    std::ofstream out("eigen.cereal", std::ios::binary);
    cereal::BinaryOutputArchive archive_o(out);
    archive_o(test);
  }

  std::cout << "test:" << std::endl << test << std::endl;

  Eigen::MatrixXd test_loaded;

  {
    std::ifstream in("eigen.cereal", std::ios::binary);
    cereal::BinaryInputArchive archive_i(in);
    archive_i(test_loaded);
  }

  std::cout << "test loaded:" << std::endl << test_loaded << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Tried your example, it works. Just stumbled on this, anyway: if I remove the brackets around the serialization, the example breaks with: terminating with uncaught exception of type cereal::Exception: Failed to read 6144 bytes from input stream! Read 4088 - Why? Is something related to Cereal? The naming is different, so...?

Comment: [@Kabu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/user-id) and others with similar questions: Brackets are key due to Cereal's RAII mechanism. Archives are flushed fully only at destruction; premature access can lead to incomplete content. While this incompleteness isn't easily noticeable with binary, the principle remains the same. For additional information, refer to [this StackOverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30194212/cereal-json-output-misses-closing-curly-brace) and this [issue on Cereal's GitHub](https://github.com/USCiLab/cereal/issues/101).

Answer (score 4):

Based on @Azoth answer (whom I would like to give the whole credit, anyway), I improved the template a bit to

- work also for `Eigen::Array` (rather than just `Eigen::Matrix`);
- not serialize compile-time dimensions (that makes quite some storage difference for e.g. `Eigen::Vector3f`).

This is the result:

```
namespace cereal
{
  template <class Archive, class Derived> inline
    typename std::enable_if<traits::is_output_serializable<BinaryData<typename Derived::Scalar>, Archive>::value, void>::type
    save(Archive & ar, Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Derived> const & m){
      typedef Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Derived> ArrT;
      if(ArrT::RowsAtCompileTime==Eigen::Dynamic) ar(m.rows());
      if(ArrT::ColsAtCompileTime==Eigen::Dynamic) ar(m.cols());
      ar(binary_data(m.data(),m.size()*sizeof(typename Derived::Scalar)));
    }

  template <class Archive, class Derived> inline
    typename std::enable_if<traits::is_input_serializable<BinaryData<typename Derived::Scalar>, Archive>::value, void>::type
    load(Archive & ar, Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Derived> & m){
      typedef Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Derived> ArrT;
      Eigen::Index rows=ArrT::RowsAtCompileTime, cols=ArrT::ColsAtCompileTime;
      if(rows==Eigen::Dynamic) ar(rows);
      if(cols==Eigen::Dynamic) ar(cols);
      m.resize(rows,cols);
      ar(binary_data(m.data(),static_cast<std::size_t>(rows*cols*sizeof(typename Derived::Scalar))));
    }
}
```