# How to write/read an Eigen matrix from binary file

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen3

To write Eigen::Matrix to file I really like to use the following:

```
typedef Eigen::Matrix<Scalar, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> Matrix_MxN;
Matrix_MxN J = Matrix_MxN::Zeros(10,10);      
std::ofstream("matrix.txt") << J;
```

But unfortunately, something that can do the opposite is not defined:

```
std::ifstream("matrix.txt") >> J;
```

To circumvent this problem, **how can you read/write an Eigen::Matrix to binary file instead**?

Comment: You can also use a serialization library, e.g. Cereal. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22884216/serializing-eigenmatrix-using-cereal-library

Answer (score 16):

You can define these methods:

```
namespace Eigen{
template<class Matrix>
void write_binary(const char* filename, const Matrix& matrix){
    std::ofstream out(filename, std::ios::out | std::ios::binary | std::ios::trunc);
    typename Matrix::Index rows=matrix.rows(), cols=matrix.cols();
    out.write((char*) (&rows), sizeof(typename Matrix::Index));
    out.write((char*) (&cols), sizeof(typename Matrix::Index));
    out.write((char*) matrix.data(), rows*cols*sizeof(typename Matrix::Scalar) );
    out.close();
}
template<class Matrix>
void read_binary(const char* filename, Matrix& matrix){
    std::ifstream in(filename, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    typename Matrix::Index rows=0, cols=0;
    in.read((char*) (&rows),sizeof(typename Matrix::Index));
    in.read((char*) (&cols),sizeof(typename Matrix::Index));
    matrix.resize(rows, cols);
    in.read( (char *) matrix.data() , rows*cols*sizeof(typename Matrix::Scalar) );
    in.close();
}
} // Eigen::
```

and you can test their usage with:

```
typedef Eigen::Matrix<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::ColMajor> Matrix_MxN; 
Matrix_MxN J = Matrix_MxN::Random(10,5);
Eigen::write_binary("matrix.dat",J);
std::cout << "\n original \n" << J << std::endl;
Matrix_MxN J_copy;
Eigen::read_binary("matrix.dat",J_copy);
std::cout << "\n copy \n" << J_copy << std::endl;
cout.flush();'
```

If you know of a better way, suggestions are welcome!

Comment: What if you were reading from an edge file? The edge file contains source and destination id pairs, assuming the file is sorted by source id. Is there an elegant way read a file like this and create a matrix in Eigen?

Comment: The sub-question is a bit OT. But there is something called "triplets" loading for matrices in Eigen (i index, j index, and value) for sparse matrices.

Comment: Notice that if you're using `Eigen` with another library which uses it (like `OpenCV`) this is gonna generate a lot of compile errors. In general it's a not a good idea inject new functions in a library `namespace`.

Comment: This doesnt work if your Matrix has a null terminator equivalent binary

Answer (score 0):

modifications to avoid intruding namespace Eigen,
using zlib for bigger Matrices.

```
#include <string>
#include <zlib.h>
#include <Eigen/Core>

namespace myEigen{
template<class Derived>
void write_binary(const std::string &filename,
    const Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Derived> &matrix)
{
    typedef typename Derived::Index Index;
    typedef typename Derived::Scalar Scalar;

    gzFile out = gzopen(filename.c_str(), "wb");
    Index rows=matrix.rows(), cols=matrix.cols();

    gzwrite(out, (char*) (&rows), sizeof(Index));
    gzwrite(out, (char*) (&cols), sizeof(Index));
    gzwrite(out, (char*) matrix.data(), rows*cols*sizeof(Scalar) );
    gzclose(out);
}

template<class Derived>
void read_binary(const std::string &filename,
    Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Derived> &matrix)
{
    typedef typename Derived::Index Index;
    typedef typename Derived::Scalar Scalar;

    gzFile in = gzopen(filename.c_str(), "rb");
    Index rows=0, cols=0;
    gzread(in, (char*) (&rows),sizeof(Index));
    gzread(in, (char*) (&cols),sizeof(Index));
    matrix.resize(rows, cols);
    gzread(in, (char*) matrix.data(), rows*cols*sizeof(Scalar) );
    gzclose(in);
}
} // myEigen::
```

Comment: Add some explanation rather than pure code would be perferred