# Write/Read sparseVector of eigen to file

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3, writefile

I just folow this :

[How to write/read an Eigen matrix from binary file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25389480/how-to-write-read-an-eigen-matrix-from-binary-file)

```
namespace Eigen{
template<class Matrix>
void write_binary(const char* filename, const Matrix& matrix){
    std::ofstream out(filename,ios::out | ios::binary | ios::trunc);
    typename Matrix::Index rows=matrix.rows(), cols=matrix.cols();
    out.write((char*) (&rows), sizeof(typename Matrix::Index));
    out.write((char*) (&cols), sizeof(typename Matrix::Index));
    out.write((char*) matrix.data(), rows*cols*sizeof(typename Matrix::Scalar) );
    out.close();
}
template<class Matrix>
void read_binary(const char* filename, Matrix& matrix){
    std::ifstream in(filename,ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    typename Matrix::Index rows=0, cols=0;
    in.read((char*) (&rows),sizeof(typename Matrix::Index));
    in.read((char*) (&cols),sizeof(typename Matrix::Index));
    matrix.resize(rows, cols);
    in.read( (char *) matrix.data() , rows*cols*sizeof(typename Matrix::Scalar) );
    in.close();
}
} // Eigen::
```

But problem is of Sparse module:
When i want to write SparseVector , I gets:

> void Eigen::write_binary(const char*, const Matrix&) [with Matrix =
>   Eigen::SparseVector]’:
>   ../re_fol/createComparisonData.cpp:54:33:   instantiated from here
>   ../re_fol/createComparisonData.cpp:33:5: error: invalid cast from type
>   ‘const Storage {aka const Eigen::internal::CompressedStorage}’ to type ‘char*’ make: *** [re_fol/createComparisonData.o] Error
>   1

iN THIS line :

```
out.write((char*) matrix.data(), rows*cols*sizeof(typename Matrix::Scalar) );
```

I know that the vector is special type of matrix in eigen, but the sparse module have some may another type of sotrage data......?:

> ```
> const Eigen::internal::CompressedStorage<double,
> > int>}’ to type ‘char*’ make:
> ```

Comment: You can try something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24593085/serializing-decomposed-matrix-from-eigen-sparselu-object/24595433#24595433).