# Cereal JSON output misses closing curly brace

Tags: c++, json, cereal

I am using [Cereal C++ v1.1.1](https://github.com/USCiLab/cereal/tree/v1.1.1) and similar to the [example](https://uscilab.github.io/cereal/serialization_archives.html) given in the documentation I am trying the following:

```cpp
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cereal/archives/json.hpp>

int main() {
  std::ostringstream os;
  cereal::JSONOutputArchive archive(os);
  int x = 12;
  archive(CEREAL_NVP(x));
  std::cout << os.str(); // JUST FOR DEMONSTRATION!
}
```

I expect to have the following:

```json
{
  "x":12
}
```

but the closing curly brace is missing. Any idea what is missing in the code?

**Update:**

adding `archive.finishNode()` seems to solve the problem. But I would say that it's not the solution. According to the [`operator()`](https://uscilab.github.io/cereal/assets/doxygen/classcereal_1_1OutputArchive.html#a48a65660f32a2b90f7ab26ebba25707c) documentation, calling the operator serializes the input parameters, why should I add the `finishNode` extra?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was having the same problem, and found the solution in a comment on an issue filed on Cereal's GitHub: https://github.com/USCiLab/cereal/issues/101

> The documentation states "Archives are designed to be used in an RAII
>   manner and are guaranteed to flush their contents only on
>   destruction..." (http://uscilab.github.io/cereal/quickstart.html).
>
> Your problem is that you are trying to print the contents of the
>   stringstream before the archive has been destroyed. At this point, the
>   archive has no idea whether you will want to write more data to it in
>   the future, so it refrains from streaming out the closing brace. You
>   need to make sure the archive's destructor has been called before
>   printing out the stringstream.
>
> Try this:
>
> ```
> int main()
> {
>   std::stringstream ss;
>   {
>     cereal::JSONOutputArchive archive( ss );
>     SomeData myData;
>     archive( myData );
>   }
>   std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;
>
>   return 0;
> }
> ```
>
> Please see the documentation for more information.